# How to integrate Zoho in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, zoho

I need to integrate Zoho CRM to my react project(External application) and am new to react.Any one can give a solution? Is this integrating through back end or front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one method which is through API's. Just go through the API docs. Api documentation has all the required information and also the sample json data. If they are not sufficient kindly try using Zoho postman collections.

Documentation: https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you wish to integrate React Project (External application) with Zoho CRM. However as now, There is no any method for direct integration of Zoho CRM - React Project. Hence, you can contact the API developer of ZOHO organisation & check the possibilities of completing the integration based on the business requirement using the API methods.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned you need to use the API's, the correct link for the CRM API is:

https://www.zoho.com/crm/catalyst/rest-api.html

A quote from Zoho:

"Zoho CRM offers the perfect collection of REST APIs and client libraries for building exciting new apps, for businesses of all sizes. The APIs are also secured by OAuth2.0 and API key methods to enable you to seamlessly integrate your Zoho CRM account with any third-party application.

Seamlessly push and receive information into your Zoho CRM account, or into any app that your team develops, using Zoho CRM API.  Extract CRM data in JSON format, including any errors using simple HTTP methods."

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is quite old now but I still would like to contribute anyway.
Zoho's API is mostly used for extension apps or integrations; not if you want to add a user when the latter submut a form on your app; and their OAuth protocol is overkill, especially if you just want to add a new contact or whatever.
Plus their documentation is reaaaaaally organized (sarcasm obviously).
The simplest way to integrate any SPA with any Zoho apps is to use Zoho Flow (10$/mo or 25$/mo).
You can seamlessly create your own API using webhooks on it AND create workflow between any Zoho apps (CRM, Campaigns, Bookings and even third party apps.

You might be asking why should you pay an extra just to call their API?

Well it's just less of a nightmare, it's a small price to pay to make everything easy with Zoho